# ed(1) script with multiple search/replace

Tags: scripting, ed

Working on a question for [codegolf.se](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/50270/codegolf-heads-or-tails), trying to do a simple text replacement.

- Given a file **`coin.txt`** containing 1 word, either `heads` or `tails`
- I have an `ed` script **`flip.ed`** as follows:

```
s/heads/1/n\
s/tails/-1/n\
wq
.
```

- Then I execute it from the terminal (macos, zsh), as follows: (per "[Ed Mastery](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07BVBSDNZ)", chapter 111)

```
[~/golf/ed]λ ed coin.txt < flip.ed; cat coin.txt  
6
?
tails
```

Expected the script to change `tails` to `-1`. I get the same problem from BSD and GNU ed (`/bin/ed` and `/usr/local/bin/ged`, and TIO.run for that matter). Neither one seems able to execute multiple replacements.

Here's an [example on TIO.run](https://tio.run/##S035/1@nWD8jNTGlWN9QP4YLyClJzMwp1tc11OcqL@TS@/8fLPn/X35BSWZ@XvF/3TIA), I think it's running GNU ed.

Is there a problem in my `ed` script? Or is it a bug in the mighty **`ed`**??

#### Update

A solution, courtesy of [@ed1conf](https://twitter.com/ed1conf) on twitter. Uses `g` prefix to only do the replacement on matching lines, thus avoiding errors that broke my original script.  [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S035/z9dPyM1MaVYv1hf31CfK12/JDEzB8zTBXLLC7n0/v8HC/3/l19QkpmfV/xftxgA)

```
g/heads/s//1/
g/tails/s//-1/
wq
.
```

Comment: What is your intention with the `/n` suffix in the `s///` command? I'm not familiar with it.

Comment: `n` is like `p` for print, but `n` gives line numbers as well. Seems to have no effect in this situation, I removed it in the TIO example

Comment: Why do you have those backslashes there? https://tio.run/##S035/1@nWD8jNTGlWN9QnwvILknMzCnW1wVyygu59P7/B8txgUX//8svKMnMzyv@r1sGAA

Comment: I was following an example from the "Ed Mastery" book, thanks for that solution! I couldn't make it work :P

Comment: The one example I saw from muru had two lines in the input, which made both searches successful. I understood your input to be one line of one word.

Comment: Ah damn, you're right. Looks like I can't do it in one `ed` script, per your answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this, but you cannot send the commands via redirection or a regular file.

From the [GNU ed online manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/ed/manual/ed_manual.html#Diagnostics):

> When an error occurs, if ed's input is from a regular file or here document, then it exits, otherwise it prints a '?' and returns to command mode.

One of the two commands will fail, since the word in the file cannot match both patterns, and so `ed` exits -- whether on line 1 because it doesn't match, or on line 2 because *it* doesn't match (and so exiting before the changed file is saved).

The commands would work (minus the backslashes and suffixes) via stdin:

```
printf '%s\n' 's/heads/1/' 's/tails/-1/' 'wq' | ed -s coin.txt
```

You'll get a `?` to stderr because the `s/heads/1/` failed (which you could redirect away), but the replacements all happen as expected.

Note that I dropped the trailing `.` command, as the `q` command is enough to exit `ed`.

---

A workaround, posted by [ed(1) Conference on Twitter](https://twitter.com/ed1conf/status/1161687587360313355), is:

```
g/heads/s//1/
g/tails/s//-1/
wq
```

or, without abbreviations in the `s///` portion:

```
g/heads/s/heads/1/
g/tails/s/tails/-1/
wq
```

These variations work because the `g` commands do not fail, even if no substitutions are performed.

Comment: BSD `ed` stops processing at the non-match, and won't get to the `wq`.

Comment: Very interesting!  Thanks for the testing. I tried some variations, like `g /heads/ s/heads/1/` but even that "fails" enough to bail out.

Comment: All true but @ed1conf on twitter demonstrated [a version that works using the `g` prefix](https://tio.run/##S035/z9dPyM1MaVYv1hf31CfK12/JDEzB8zTBXLLC7n0/v8HC/3/l19QkpmfV/xftxgA) to avoid the errors.

Comment: I could have sworn I tried that (the expanded `g/heads/ s/heads/1/` version) but failed. If you have a link to the tweet, I'd love to include it.

Comment: here's the [tweeted solution from @ed1conf](https://twitter.com/ed1conf/status/1161687587360313355), and [my golfed version on codegolf.se](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/189998/15940). Thanks heaps! :)

Comment: Ah, so the `g` command does not "fail" if the address is not found?

Comment: Interestingly, the script works with `g/heads/...` but not with `g /heads/...` despite the `info` page showing a space between `g` and `/RE/`. The online web page does *not* have a space after `g`.

Answer (score 1):

With `sed`, you could do it with

```
sed 's/heads/tails/;t;s/tails/heads/'
```

In `ed`, the `t` command is a completely different command and won't "branch if the most recent substitution did something".

With GNU `ed`, you could do

```
printf '%s\n' '1s/heads/T/' '1s/tails/H/' '1s/H/heads/' '1s/T/tails/' 'wq' | ed -s coin.txt
```

to do your flip, but it may not work in BSD `ed` as the processing of the commands stop at the first substitution that does not match, because

> When an error in the input script is encountered, or when an error is detected that is a consequence of the data (not) present in the file or due to an external condition such as a read or write error:
>
> - If the standard input is a terminal device file, all input shall be flushed, and a new command read.
> - **If the standard input is a regular file, `ed` shall terminate with a non-zero exit status.**

(that's from [the POSIX standard](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/ed.html))

The errors you get from GNU `ed` when running this script are "No match" errors (visible if you insert the `H` command first in the script), and can safely be ignored.